# Using a Maven plugin to extract parameters injected using Spring

Tags: java, maven

I have an application which uses Spring to wire up some beans in various combinations.
Below are simplified classes which help to illustrate the the relevant part of the application.

```
class A {
   private List<B> fieldB;

    public void setFieldB(List<B> fieldB) { this.fieldB = fieldB; }
    public List<B> getFieldB() { return this.fieldB; }
}

class B {
    private String name;
    private String field1;
    private String field2;

    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
    public void setField1(String value1) { this.field1 = value1; }
    public void setField2(String value2) { this.field2 = value2; }

    public String getName() { return this.name; }
    public String getField1() { return this.field1; }
    public String getField2() { return this.field2; }
}
```

spring-context-file1.xml

```
<?xml ...>
<beans ...>
    <bean id="a" class="com.example.A">
        <property name="fieldB">
           <list> <ref bean="b1"/> <ref bean="b2"/> </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="b1" class="com.example.B">
        <property name="name">
           <value>b1</value>
        </property>
        <property name="field1">
           <value>fieldOneValueOne</value>
        </property>
        <property name="field2">
           <value>fieldOneValueTwo</value>
        </property>
    <bean>

    <bean id="b2" class="com.example.B">
        <property name="name">
           <value>b2</value>
        </property>
        <property name="field1">
           <value>fieldTwoValueOne</value>
        </property>
        <property name="field2">
           <value>fieldTwoValueTwo</value>
        </property>
    <bean>
</beans>
```

Given the above what I would like to do is have the following information extracted at build time:

```
spring-context-file1.cfg  
b1 => {fieldOneValueOne, fieldOneValueTwo}  
b2 => {fieldTwoValueOne, fieldTwoValueTwo}
```

I have opted to develop a Maven plugin to do this requisite processing. Basically the plugin will load up the Spring context file and use the getBean("...") method to get the beans of interest. I have however run into a problem. In order to extract the information from the beans the plugin code needs to know what type of object it's manipulating. This means the plugin code will need to be compiled against the main project code. This seems wrong to me.
Does any know of any means for a Maven plugin to extract this sort of information?

Comment: why don't you use a xml parser directly ?

Comment: And duplicate the functionality provided by org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext. Somehow I don't think that's such a good idea...

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of extracting the information from the Spring config file, you should create a common file that the Spring context can load bean properties from. Then you can parse this file quite easily at build time (hopefully without writing a custom Maven plugin - this will complicate your build horribly). Have a look at the new property management in Spring 3.1: http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/15/spring-3-1-m1-unified-property-management/

Comment: Say for example a number of As and Bs are created. And using <ref bean ..> these are then wired up in different permutations. This suggestion would not work. As the "configuration" is now embedded in the spring context file and to extract it you need to read the object to see how they were wired up.

Comment: Sure, it certainly depends on your configuration. But without knowing the full extent of what you want to do, I can't offer more advice. It is likely that there is a simpler solution than what you're doing. Maybe you could update the question with more context.